# TYPO3 9.5 Sorting of child-elements from parent

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have a problem finding a simple and easy solution to sort child-elements in it's parent. I don't want to have them sorted by the `sorting`-property of the child but some other value (in this example `sort_value`).

The parent has the property `child_elements`, and the child has a property `sort_value`.

I've already tried adding the following statement to the `defaultOrderings` of the `ParentRepository`:

```
'child_elements.sort_value' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_DESCENDING
```

I've also tried with `childElements.sort_value` and `childElements.sortValue` but that didn't work in either way.

I've found some solutions like sorting the children in the template using vhs-viewhelper or with injecting the `childRepository` into the `ParentModel` which then calls the `findAll`-function on the child in the getter-function of the parent (which is really dirty)...

Is there a mistake I'm not aware of in the `defaultOrderings`-statement? Or is there simply not such a simple way to do it?

The `childRepository` already has it's `defaultOrderings` set to the `sortValue`. The functions used for getting the parent is `findAll` or `findByUid` so no custom repository function.

*What I want* is to get the parent-object with it's sorted children by the children's field `sort_value`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe one of this helps: https://blog.teamgeist-medien.de/2014/12/extbase-sortierung-von-child-objects-objectstorages-irre.html  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807394/typo3-extbase-how-to-sort-child-objects

Comment: @exotec I've already found and tried the solution in the blog-post but it didn't work. Nothing changed at all. For the time being I've used the v:sort with an iteration in fluid but it's not my preferred solution. I'm surprised that there doesn't seem to exist such a "simple" functionality (which could be solved with the solution above with defaultSorting)...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about IRRE fields. Then you can sort them by adding a `foreign_default_sortby` to the parent's TCA like that:

```php
'child_elements' => [
    ...
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'inline',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_myextension_any_table',
        'foreign_field' => 'my_join_field',
        'foreign_default_sortby' => 'sort_value DESC',
        ...
    ],
],
```

Remember to remove `foreign_sortby` if there is one because it will overwrite the `foreign_default_sortby`.

See: [TCA Reference: IRRE / foreign_default_sortby](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline/Properties/ForeignDefaultSortby.html)